# Does 'adb backup -apk' stores application private data?

Tags: android, adb

As can be seen at title, my question is it: does the command:

```
adb backup -apk -shared -all -f /home/me/my-device.bkp
```

Stores application private data? Such those at SharedPreferences; files stored at any context.getApplicationPrivateStorage() and databases created trough SQLiteOpenHelper?

I'm willing to do that so I can throw my phone from a building :P

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider the case when you call:

```
adb uninstall ...
```

(in this case your application with all local private data is removed (you application data that stored on the SD Card - not deleted (for example your can store here you sqlite db))

so I think it's logical that `adb backup -apk` knows about your private data and can backup it if you use proper flags.

It seems that this case is not covered here 
   http://developer.android.com/tools/help/bmgr.html.

Comment: Well, trough BackupManager it allows to backup single apps trough it's package name. I wish to do a full phone backup and when restoring it to a newly phone I want my highscores at Cute The Rope and Pudding to be restored as well.

Comment: You can get the full list of your installed packages and backup them separately, but it seems that there should be a more friendly way to do it.

Comment: Hmm... that will be a boring task =/ And i'll only discover if it stores private data after test.

Comment: try to explore : https://github.com/search?l=Java&q=backup&ref=cmdform&type=Repositories

Answer (score 1):

It always saves private data, the `-apk` and `-shared` flags control whether it stores binaries (APKs) and external storage (SD card files) in addition to that.

Comment: Great to know, unfortunately, this does looks like that it's only Android 4.0+ I'm storing /sdcard and /mnt/asec and hope that this is all of my content

Comment: in addition to that, which is the folder where SMS are storeds? Or should I use any of those backup apps that do that?

Comment: `/sdcard` is backed up if specify the `-shared` option. `/mnt/asec` is   a virtual folder, you shouldn't need to back it up manually if you specified `-apk`. SMS are inside the data folder of messaging provider , but may not be backed up if it doesn't allow it. BTW, this is not a programming question at all, try http://android.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Oh.. trues.. it's not a programming question, I tried login in another stack services but i didnt remember my credentials =/